# How to create a list view with Edit and Save buttons in frontend part of Joomla! 3 component?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla-extensions, web-frontend, joomla3.9

I'm trying to develop Joomla! 3 component which have a view for displaying the list of some entities among with Create and Edit buttons for creating and editing an item of this list accordinaly. This view have to be displayed in frontend.
Can you help me to find out what code should be in the view.html.php, model and controller files?

Comment: You will get the docs here https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange then please custom flag this question to be migrated to JSE.